# How do I get the Content-Type of my Current View in PHP

Tags: php, content-type

I'm using PHP 5.3.13. I'm trying to change my logging so if the page has `header('Content-type: text/plain')`, it outputs logs in plain text. If html, I want them in html format.

I've tried:

- `getallheaders()` Fatal error: Call to undefined function getallheaders()
- `mime_content_type()` Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type()
- `apache_request_headers()` Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_request_headers()
- `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` returns empty

Edited to show error messages on what I've tried.

Comment: try `mime_content_type($filename)`

Comment: What are the fatal errors you are getting with `getallheaders()` and `apache_request_headers()`? How are you running PHP?

Comment: All errors are `Call to undefined function`. I've updated my question to reflect those attempts and errors.

Comment: I'm running php in my browser. I'm trying to determine the content-type of the file that is being run from within that document. There has to be a way to do this.

Comment: @dovidev what do you mean you are running php in your browser? PHP is a server side language - I tried looking up running php files in the browser to check and this is what I find http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/running-php-files/

Comment: @Kvothe Yes, the php file is running on a linux server at GoDaddy. I'm accessing it in my browser as opposed to from the command line. That's the distinction I was answering for.